# Converting a tuple into an integer in python 3?

Tags: python, int, tuples

I have a tuple with a single value that's the result of a database query (it gives me the max ID # currently in the database). I need to add 1 to the value to utilize for my subsequent query to create a new profile associated with the next ID #.

Having trouble converting the tuple into an integer so that I can add 1 (tried the roundabout way here by turning the values into a string and then turning into a int). Help, please.

```
sql = """
SELECT id
FROM profiles
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
"""

cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
maxID = int(','.join(str(results)))
newID = maxID + 1
```

Comment: To get the first (AKA only) element of a 1-element tuple, do `mytuple[0]` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting just the one row, then use [`cursor.fetchone()`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) instead of `fetchall()` and simply index into the one row that that method returns:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
newID = row[0] + 1
```

Rather than use an `ORDER BY`, you can ask the database directly for the maximum value:

```
sql = """SELECT MAX(id) FROM profiles"""
```